# code.exe blocked after choosing wrong option in update via integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, blocking

I opened VSCode for the first time in a while, and when I went to use the integrated terminal there was some dialog about updating or allowing a publisher.

I was in a rush and wasn't sure what was going on, it was saying something about allowing a file from an "unknown publisher" and I believe I chose "always block" or something like that, and now I can't launch VSCode unless I do so through an elevated terminal. I get this pop up when trying to launch the app:

[image]

I wish I had more information I could give you but I just really didn't pay enough attention to the prompt. Nevertheless I've been searching for hours now and can't seem to fix this, pretty sure I blocked some low level file and have no way of locating it. Doesn't seem like there's any comprehensive list as to what's been blocked anywhere in Windows, I fear I may need to do a system restore to fix this.

Uninstalling and re-installing VSCode doesn't fix the problem, Any ideas?

UPDATE - Here's a screenshot of the certificate I accidentally blocked, removing it from the Untrusted Certificates > Certificates folder fixed the problem:
[image]

Comment: [The simplest solution to is change the UAC protection to warn instead of block.  Have you tried that?](https://cdn.appuals.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-46.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `certmgr.msc`:

- Certificates that are trusted without prompting are under `Trusted Publishers`.
- Certificates that are immediately rejected are under `Untrusted Certificates`.

Although the first thing that's unusual is that you were seeing "Unknown Publisher", when Visual Studio Code executables normally are digitally signed by Microsoft. If reinstalling VSCode didn't help, something else is going wrong...

Comment: Thank you so much, was really starting to tear my hair out with this one. I'm not sure why anything was described as an "unknown publisher" because it looks like the cert was issued by Microsoft themselves (see edited post). But it also said "unknown publisher" in the terminal prompt that led to all of this, which is why I chose to block it, I'd never seen a prompt like that in VSCode's integrated terminal. Either way, deleting the cert / removing it from the Untrusted Certificates > Certificates folder has fixed the issue. Hope I don't run into this again, but now I know right where to look.